# Doit-on utiliser il/elle quand le sujet est indirect?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, adjectifs

Par exemple, j'ai une phrase dans laquelle le sujet est utilisé pour un homme/une femme :

*Si le sujet n’est pas en mesure de réaliser certaines activités en raison de son lieu de résidence, estimez ce qu’il serait susceptible d'accomplir dans un autre cadre.*

Pour être plus "respectueux", dois-je utiliser :

*Si le sujet n’est pas en mesure de réaliser certaines activités en raison de son lieu de résidence, estimez ce qu’il/elle serait susceptible d'accomplir dans un autre cadre.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dans te première phrase, l'utilisation de *il* est correcte : le mot auquel il se rapporte est masculin, et de plus, *il* peut servir de pronom neutre (quand le genre du sujet est inconnu).

Cependant, ta seconde phrase est aussi exacte ! En effet, ton sujet peut être un homme ou une femme, son genre t'est inconnu. Dans ce cas, il est aussi correct d'utiliser *il/elle*.

Ecrire *il* ou *il/elle* dépend en fait de ce que tu écris, du message que tu veux faire passer, de tes lecteurs, etc. Mais en effet, on peut considérer que la seconde solution soit plus respectueuse, car inclusive.

Comment: Merci pour votre aide